# Error communicating with OpenAI: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openai.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: ssl, openai-api

I'm using an EC2 server and have installed SSL on it. I also connected my GoDaddy domain with an A DNS record. However, when I call the OpenAI API

```
def call_openai(search_prompt, engine='text-davinci-003', temp=0.3, top_p=1.0, tokens=400, freq_pen=0.0, pres_pen=0.0, stop=['END']):
    prompt = search_prompt.encode(encoding='ASCII',errors='ignore').decode()
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine=engine,
        prompt=prompt,
        temperature=temp,
        max_tokens=tokens,
        top_p=top_p,
        frequency_penalty=freq_pen,
        presence_penalty=pres_pen,
        stop=stop)
    text = response['choices'][0]['text'].strip()
    return text
```

using the Python SDK, I receive the following error message:

```
openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openai.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions (Caused by SSLError(PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')))
```

Please note that when I enter the IP address of the server in the browser, it does not seem secure but my domain is secured when use it to show ec2 content.

How can I fix this error?